# Keyboard's 'G' button not working

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure, laptop-repair

My laptop keyboard's "G" button has stopped working all of a sudden.

I didn't make any update or any hardware change. I have to use on screen keyboard to type "G" alphabet.

I use Linux but checked on BIOS too, still not working, probably hardware problem.

Do I need to change whole keyboard or specific key can be changed?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Knowing the model of the laptop would be nice considering it _is_ a hardware issue (based from what you said).

Comment: @Insane LAPTOP MODEL is HP 630.

Answer (score 0):

This happens all the time, Sorry your going to have to replace the entire keyboard. Its an internal hardware issue on the keyboard. Replacing just the key will not help. Most laptop Keyboards cost between 20-40 dollars.